# How To get Join Result in different key Json in Laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, api, rest

Have Two Tables 1)Products and 2)Images.How to get this output in Api
Laravel? I tried Join . But want images result in json key . Have Two Tables 1)Products and 2)Images.How to get this output in Api
Laravel? I tried Join . But want images result in json key .

```
  "products": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "title": "Check Grand Deal Slam Indoor Of Show Jumping Novel",
                        "is_featured": false,
                        "is_hot": false,
                        "price": 41.99,
                        "sale_price": 32.99,
                        "vendor": "Roberts Store",
                        "review": 4,
                        "is_out_of_stock": false,
                        "depot": 68,
                        "inventory": 90,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "is_sale": true,
                        "created_at": "2020-03-15T06:04:35.781Z",
                        "updated_at": "2020-04-14T10:46:09.145Z",
                        "variants": [],
                        "images": [
                            {
                                "id": 24,
                                "name": "6a.jpg",
                                "alternativeText": null,
                                "caption": null,
                                "width": null,
                                "height": null,
                                "formats": null,
                                "hash": "5c7442b5104545afa78bfe819616d298",
                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                "size": 52.29,
                                "url": "/static/uploads/5c7442b5104545afa78bfe819616d298.jpg",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "created_at": "2020-03-15T06:07:56.574Z",
                                "updated_at": "2020-03-15T06:07:56.574Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 25,
                                "name": "6a.jpg",
                                "alternativeText": null,
                                "caption": null,
                                "width": null,
                                "height": null,
                                "formats": null,
                                "hash": "0a9100b8791b44ff9629377856bab05a",
                                "ext": ".jpg",
                                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                                "size": 52.29,
                                "url": "/static/uploads/0a9100b8791b44ff9629377856bab05a.jpg",
                                "previewUrl": null,
                                "provider": "local",
                                "provider_metadata": null,
                                "created_at": "2020-03-15T06:07:56.593Z",
                                "updated_at": "2020-03-15T06:07:56.593Z"
                            }
                        ],
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done already, create `Eloquent` models with relationships. Which assume image have a `product_id` column.

```
class Product {
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}

class Image {
    
}
```

From here you can use `with()` from Eloquent, to include images on responses. Transforming your models into the correct serialization with two array, while giving it the `JSON` key you want. So your response will be achieved by.

```
return [
    'products' => Product::with('images')->get()->toArray(),
];
```